# how to use migrations properly

Tags: node.js, migration, sequelize.js

My question is a bit abstract, but I hope that not too much.

I am building a project that's using Sequelize as it's ORM. It's already in production, meaning I have data in my database that CANNOT be deleted. Since we still develop, I sometimes need to change the database (alter a column, add a column, delete a column).

In the project I am using `sequelize.sync()`. The only option to enforce changes in database is with `sequelize.sync({force: true})`, but this command deletes all data from database.

To my understanding I need to use migrations. Sadly, I have read the documentation and looked in Stack Overflow and I still couldn't find a proper guide on how to do a migration and keep your data.

Let's say I have a model, `User`:

```
module.exports = (sequelize, DataTypes) => {
  var Users = sequelize.define('user', {
    id: {
      type: DataTypes.UUID,
      defaultValue: DataTypes.UUIDV4,
      primaryKey: true
    },
    username: {
      type: DataTypes.STRING(20),
      unique: {
        msg: 'A person with the same username already exists!'
      },
      allowNull: false
    }, 
    password: {
      type: DataTypes.STRING(100),
      allowNull: false
    },
    phone: {
      type: DataTypes.STRING(50),
      allowNull: true,
      unique: {
        msg: 'A user with the same phone number already exists!'
      }
    }
  });

  Users.associate = function (models) {
    models.user.User_roles = models.user.belongsTo(models.user_role, {foreignKey: 'role'});

    models.user.Site_access = models.user.hasMany(models.site_access, {
      as: 'site_access',
      onDelete: "CASCADE",
      foreignKey: {
        allowNull: false
      }
    });
  };
  return Users;
};
```

Say I wanted to add a column `birthday TIMESTAMP` without erasing all existing data, how can I do so?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add columns in your `User` table and use `alter`

```
sequelize.sync({
    force: false,
    alter: true
 })
```

The `alter` true is gonna only update new columns or deleted columns without delete datas.

Comment: Oh really? and what about altering a column?

Comment: If you change username to name , existing username column datas are deleted and name column created null by set `defaultValue: null`

Comment: I see, so it's still dangerous. Thank you so much for your help! I can't find any documentation on this alter property so you really helped alot.

Comment: yeah alter is dangerous for production, be careful of this. anyway I'm glad to help you :)

Answer (score 0):

As an alternative also you can use the [Sequelize CLI](https://github.com/sequelize/cli) instead of using the models sync. This allows you to also create more complicated migrations, with rollbacks, and seeders along with your models.

Comment: Is sequelize-cli a complete alternative to the models + sync system?

Comment: Instead of the sync system. I use the sequelize cli in my projects to write migrations and create seeders. It allows us to have data integrity and write more complicated migration logic beyond columns. Sequelize init will setup the folders you need. I think you just need to setup the config file.